# Algebra/Ring Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was reading this paper by Taelman and also from Anderson and apparently they have used this idea:

> Let $A$ be a finitely generated $F_{q}$ algebra. Assume that for every maximal ideal $I$ in $A$ the residue field $A/I$ is of degree at least $d$ over $F_{q}$ then the set $\{a-a^{q}\}$ generates the unit ideal of $A$.

Why is this so?

Thanks for helping. I am going to be so destroyed if I can't see why.

Comment: The statement you have quoted looks suspicious since it makes no use of the quantity $d$.

Comment: First, is $\;\{a-a^q\}\;$ to be understood as the set of all elements of that form when $\;a\;$ runs over all elements of $\;A\;$ ? Second, what do **you** call "the unit ideal" of $\;A\;$ to?